# Is it a good idea to add time-consuming method or property to django model?

Tags: django, django-models

This is the model:

```
class Sensor(models.Model):
  sensor_id = models.CharField(...)
  ...
  @property
  def get_data(self, self_id):
    #get data using paho-mqtt package
```

Is it a good idea to add time-consuming method or property to django model or should I separate the time-consuming action outside the model?

Answer (score 0):

If it a time-consuming method you should consider using the [cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) decorator, like this:

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

@cached_property
def get_data(self, self_id):
    #get data using paho-mqtt package
```

Comment: If I need the real-time data, Can I use this decorator?

Comment: I believe so, yes!